# When and how to increase version numbers (Maven, Java, Sonar)?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, pom.xml

I have a Java project, which is still in a very early stage. There are no real releases yet, so I set version as 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in my pom.xml.

Before each submit, I perform a Sonar analysis directly from Maven using:

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Sonar has this nice ability to record changes of KPIs over time. However, it only does that for a version. Now, as I don't update my version number, it overrides the last analysis result and replaces it with the current one.

I wonder how to get around that. I don't want to increase version numbers manually each day as this doesn't seem very natural to me.

What other options do I have? Should I use one of the Maven plugins to add a build number to the version string so that I have unique versions? Do you have any other strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want increase version number every release, the [maven release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) is recommendation.

But if you want increase the version number everyday even every build, you can use unique version number like timestamp which can get from Maven building phase, after Maven 2.1, it has the built-in `${maven.build.timestamp}` you can use, and you can use format

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

for more information you can visit http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: I like the idea of adding a day timestamp to the version number. This could do the trick. Let's see if someone else has a different answer to it.

Comment: maybe you can check [maven buildnumber plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Sonar does preserve the metrics for each snapshot build (based on your configuration).  You can then rename the snapshots suitably and use them to get [historical information](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Historical+Information#HistoricalInformation-ManagingHistory).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don't to releases yet. As soon as you do, the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) is a recommendation. It handles the SVN related stuff that comes with a release.

I'm not sure if this helps you with day-to-day work on a SNAPSHOT, though.